FFMPEG - Combine audio file into a mkv & set the track as primary
I'm fairly new to using ffmpeg via the command line.  I've created a python script to combine/merge an audio track with a mkv file. 
The issue is it's adding the track as the last track to the mkv, instead of as the default track.  So it works, but I have to change the audio track before each episode.  I'd prefer to have the eac3 audio track listed first, and any other tracks listed after.  The number of other tracks may vary, sometimes there's only one, and sometimes there are multiple.  I would also like to retain any subtitle tracks within the mkv. Both the mkv and eac3 files are in the same directly.
Files
show.mkv
show.eac3
The script:
import os
import subprocess

# Define the root directory containing the subfolders with MKV files
root_dir = r'Z:\TV_shows_ended\XXXX\Season 2'

def process_files(root_dir):
    for subdir, _, files in os.walk(root_dir):
        mkv_files = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.mkv')]

        for mkv_file in mkv_files:
            base_name = os.path.splitext(mkv_file)[0]
            mkv_path = os.path.join(subdir, mkv_file)
            eac3_path = os.path.join(subdir, f"{base_name}.eac3")
            output_mkv_path = os.path.join(subdir, f"{base_name}.eac3+original.mkv")

            if os.path.exists(eac3_path):
                # FFmpeg command to combine the E-AC-3 file back into the MKV
                cmd = [
                    'ffmpeg',
                    '-i', mkv_path,
                    '-i', eac3_path,
                    '-map', '0',  # Map all streams from the original file
                    '-map', '1:a',  # Map the E-AC-3 audio from the new file
                    '-c', 'copy',  # Copy all streams without re-encoding
                    '-disposition:a:0', 'default',  # Set the E-AC-3 track as default
                    # '-disposition:a:1', '0',  # Remove default disposition from the original track
                    output_mkv_path
                ]

                print(f"Processing file: {mkv_path}")
                try:
                    result = subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
                    print(result.stdout)
                    print(f"Successfully combined {eac3_path} with {mkv_file} into {output_mkv_path}")
                except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                    print(f"Failed to combine {eac3_path} with {mkv_file}.")
                    print(e.stderr)
            else:
                print(f"E-AC-3 file not found for {mkv_file}. Skipping...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_files(root_dir)

FFMPEG Version 
ffmpeg version N-116395-g4acb9b7d10-20240723 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 14.1.0 (crosstool-NG 1.26.0.93_a87bf7f)
configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-libxml2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-chromaprint --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libdvdread --enable-libdvdnav --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libvpl --enable-openal --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --enable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --cc=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc --cxx=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ --ar=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ar --ranlib=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ranlib --nm=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-nm --extra-version=20240723 
libavutil      59. 28.100 / 59. 28.100
libavcodec     61. 10.100 / 61. 10.100
libavformat    61.  5.101 / 61.  5.101
libavdevice    61.  2.100 / 61.  2.100
libavfilter    10.  2.102 / 10.  2.102
libswscale      8.  2.100 /  8.  2.100
libswresample   5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
libpostproc    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100

try → ... -map 0:v -map 1:a -map 0:a? -map 0:s? ...

Thanks for the help.  However, being a newbie, I wasn't sure how to implement it based on your response. I was able to figure it out with the help of AI. This script adds the newly merged eac3 track as the primary.
import os
import subprocess

# Define the root directory containing the subfolders with MKV files
root_dir = r'Z:\TV_shows_ended\xxxx\Season 2'

def process_files(root_dir):
    for subdir, _, files in os.walk(root_dir):
        mkv_files = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.mkv')]
        for mkv_file in mkv_files:
            base_name = os.path.splitext(mkv_file)[0]
            mkv_path = os.path.join(subdir, mkv_file)
            eac3_path = os.path.join(subdir, f"{base_name}.eac3")
            output_mkv_path = os.path.join(subdir, f"{base_name}.eac3+aac.mkv")
            
            if os.path.exists(eac3_path):
                # FFmpeg command to combine the E-AC-3 file back into the MKV
                cmd = [
                    'ffmpeg',
                    '-i', mkv_path,
                    '-i', eac3_path,
                    '-map', '0:v',  # Map video from the original file
                    '-map', '1:a',  # Map the E-AC-3 audio from the new file
                    '-map', '0:a?', # Map all other audio tracks from the original file
                    '-map', '0:s?', # Map all subtitle tracks from the original file
                    '-map', '0:t?', # Map all attachment tracks from the original file
                    '-c', 'copy',  # Copy all streams without re-encoding
                    '-disposition:a:0', 'default',  # Set the E-AC-3 track as default
                    '-disposition:a:1', 'none',  # Remove default disposition from other tracks
                    '-metadata:s:a:0', 'title=E-AC-3',  # Set the name of the E-AC-3 track
                    '-metadata:s:a:0', 'language=eng',  # Set the language of the E-AC-3 track
                    output_mkv_path
                ]
                print(f"Processing file: {mkv_path}")
                try:
                    result = subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
                    print(result.stdout)
                    print(f"Successfully combined {eac3_path} with {mkv_file} into {output_mkv_path}")
                except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                    print(f"Failed to combine {eac3_path} with {mkv_file}.")
                    print(e.stderr)
            else:
                print(f"E-AC-3 file not found for {mkv_file}. Skipping...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_files(root_dir)

